# Is it possible to change an EC2 instance key name as shown in the AWS console?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I changed the AWS key for SSH access to an EC2 instance by creating a new key from the console and then added the public key value to authorized_key file, which worked as expected.

However, in the AWS console it is still showing the old key name as key for that instance. Will it be problem in long run in any case? How can I change the old key name to the newly created key name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the initial key name of an [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance as shown in the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/).

However, as you've already explored, it is not a problem to add another key for every day usage and won't be a problem in the long run either; in fact, you could also delete the former key pair via the AWS Management Console with zero impact on your already created instances, please see Eric Hammond's answer to [consequences of deleted key pair on ec2 instance](https://serverfault.com/a/382137/10305) for more details on the subject matter.

Comment: hey, thanks for your response. what if I move my existing amazon instance to larger/smaller instance, can that be a problem? i mean since amazon has in their record my old key for that instance so is there any chance that my new key wont work then for sshing?

Comment: @smita: If you mean stopping an instance, changing the instance type and starting it again, then no, this isn't a problem, because this doesn't change anything on your instances volumes, just the virtual hardware executing your otherwise unmodified instance; I scale up and down vertically like this all the time without any issues, i.e. this works as explained by Eric Hammond: the key definition is really just used once for the initial instance provisioning and the public key is stored on the instance thereafter.

Comment: yes for scaling up and down, I just stop it change the type and restart. thanks a lot it was really helpful.